# Does one need cash in Australia?

Tags: australia, money, payment-cards, sydney, melbourne

As far as I understand, most (if not all) places in Australia accept credit cards. But are there scenarios when one would still need cash or when using cash is more advantageous? To be specific, I'm talking about Sydney (+ Katoomba) and Melbourne. Particularly,

- Are there any places that have a minimum limit that you have to pay in order to use credit cards? If so, what kind of places are these and are they widespread?
- Do all small Chinese restaurants accept credit cards (which is not the case in the US)?
- Are there any fees that one has to pay additionally in order to use a credit card in some places (when using a VISA or MasterCard with no FTF)?

Comment: Last time I was there (last fall), cards seems to be accepted everywhere for everything, regardless how small the purchase. Just make sure you have a card that doesn't charge a foreign transaction fee. I think the system is called "EFTPOS" and you see the signs for it pretty much everywhere. Regular US credit card seemed to work fine

Comment: *Just make sure you have a card that doesn't charge a foreign transaction fee.* — if they don't, they probably charge instead by currency markup or general card fees.  There's no such thing as completely free currency exchange.  When comparing cards, make sure to take all costs into account, including hidden costs.

Comment: @gerrit: not if you get the right card. My travel card does convert currency at the current exchange rate without any fees or surcharges AND I get 2.66% cash back. I verified the exchange rates a few times on my statements and it always checked out. No hidden fees.

Comment: @Hilmar What card is this, and how do they make money (1) they don't change for the card, (2) they give you money, (3) they don't charge you for anything, and (4) they use the mid-market exchange rate? What's the catch? Apart from fintech (which have openly communicated fees) I've never seen a card or service without hidden fees.

Comment: @gerrit: happy to explain how and why this works but perhaps as answer to a new question here or on https://money.stackexchange.com/ Short version: the merchant pays a 3%-5% fee and money credit card customers are dumb enough to carry a balance.

Comment: @Hilmar [Asked](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/111053/9083).  I find your claim odd, as many websites claim mid-market rates are not available to consumers and when I compare the [Mastercard exchange rate](https://www.mastercard.co.uk/en-gb/consumers/get-support/convert-currency.html) with the [XE mid-market exchange rate](https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=10%2C000&From=RUB&To=EUR) for 10,000 ₽ to €, the Mastercard exchange rate is NOT the mid-market rate — it is (slightly) worse.

Comment: @gerrit I cannot comment on Money Stackexchange, but my debit card (from an internationally unknown bank) has 5% cashback (on rotating categories of my choice), no FTF, no AF, no ATM withdrawal fee worldwide if withdrawing more than $100 (otherwise $5 fee), and it converts currency at the current exchange rate. I've used for 2 years now it in at least 6 countries, and I cannot see any hidden fees.

Comment: @user77409 I've searched for such cards in The Netherlands, Sweden, Canada, United Kingdom, and Germany, but never found any, but started using the Transferwise Card as soon as it became available, which does charge fees but, unlike any bank I've ever used, doesn't lie about them.  I'm quite puzzled by those mystery cards that people are referring to.  Maybe it's something for "VIP" customers only (spending a lot and keeping large balances in current accounts or so)?

Comment: I did have no-fee bank accounts, ATM cards, or debit cards in some countries, but usually only if I kept a minimum balance or had a regular income.  Banks need to make money too.  Again: there's no such thing as free lunch — where's the catch?

Comment: @gerrit The card I'm using is available to general public. In fact, it is one of the most popular cards in Russia, and the bank issuing it (which is an online bank with no branches) is the largest card issuer in Russia, according to what I read. And you don't need to have any income to get this card. I forgot to mention that you have to keep at least $1000 in the bank account/on the debit card to avoid the AF, otherwise it's $1 per month (which is still a ridiculous fee).

Comment: @gerrit Probably they can afford it because they don't have physical branches? I don't know, I'm not an expert in finance. (Also, an addition if you are interested: for cards in RUB you also get 6% interest on whatever amount of money you have on your debit card (or, as you would say in the US, in your bank account). For cards in USD this rate is only 0.1%, but if one already has their card, a savings account with 2.5% yield rate can be opened within a few minutes, and such savings accounts are hard to find in the US.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95917/discussion-between-gerrit-and-user77409).

Comment: @Hilmar My question over there is probably going to be closed as off-topic, perhaps you can expand on where the catch is in [Chat]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my trip, I found that there are enough places (the vast majority of them being budget Asian restaurants) interesting for me that are cash only, both in Sydney and Melbourne, so in my situation it made sense to have some cash. A considerable number of places have a surcharge for using a credit/debit card (which is, from what I've seen, mostly below 1%, which is fine if the card gives you 1% cashback on everything; but some places had higher surcharges like 1.5%). I've barely seen any minimum transaction limits to be able to use a credit card. The upshot is that one doesn't need cash unless they are specifically interested in those budget Asian restaurants (you can find many others that accept cards).

Answer (score 5):

While you can get by without using cash for much of the time in Australia, there are exceptions:

- I have seen places that have a minimum limit for credit card transactions (where there is a minimum, it's often $10 or possibly $20).
- Virtually every restaurant will accept credit cards. Street vendors might or might not.
- Some places may charge an extra fee for using a credit card. This, like the minimum transaction limit, should be clearly indicated.

Comment: Within the cities, every establishment accepts cards. Some places in towards the suburbs and regions deal only in cash, and they mention that on the counter.